# how can i do google image search by image file(Not URL)　with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio, google-image-search

I've looked around so long, but never resolve.

this is with one condition,not using "Google custom API".

I DID searched some way, but i couldn't resolve yet.

this is the way i tried.

```
`var client = require('cheerio-httpcli');
  var word = 'http://kusatsuonsen.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/dsc_7661.jpg';
  client.fetch('https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?site=search&sa=X&image_url'
  , { q: word }, 
  function (err, $, res) {
   console.log(res.headers);
   console.log($('title').text());
  ('a').each(function (idx) {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  });
  });`
```

how can i do?

Is there any way to do so, if so can anybody point me in the right direction, i just can't seem to get started.

Comment: If you want to use Google's API without using Google's API and you have read https://developers.google.com/image-search/ and you don't intend to violate their license conditions/restrictions then one direction to help you get started and move forward might be to ask service provider's support for help. Google corporation has several thousand smart employees able to assist you. From Stack Overflow perspective I don't understand your goal, practical aspect of your question and why the Stack Overflow community should try to help you solve the problem - where's the motivation factor

Comment: thanks @xmojmr!
i wont violate.
ill ask some questions.